# Capture process output with sed, capture block of text and then filter inside it

Tags: bash, grep, sed, gnu

There is some stdout that I would like to filter with sed but I don't know how. The stdout example would be:

```
.
.
.
Model a.             # This should be captured
.
.
.
Metrics results:     # This should be captured
==================== # This should be captured
metric 1             # This should be captured
metric 2             # This should be captured
metric 3             # This should be captured
==================== # This should be captured
.
.
.
Model b              # This should be captured
.
.
.
Metrics results:     # This should be captured
==================== # This should be captured
metric 1             # This should be captured
metric 2             # This should be captured
metric 3             # This should be captured
==================== # This should be captured
.
.
.
```

Where `.` represents a line containing any random characters.
So the result would be

```
Model a
Metrics results:
====================
metric 1
metric 2
metric 3
====================
Model b
Metrics results:
====================
metric 1
metric 2
metric 3
====================
```

What sed command could I use? Would also appreciate the explanation on how it works to learn about sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you require `sed`, but there is [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) among the tags. For such filtering `grep` seems a more natural choice to me.

```
grep -E '^Model |^[Mm]etrics? |^=+$'
```

Here I tried to create a compact expression, but note `[Mm]etrics?`  will not filter out e.g. `Metric whatever` and `^=+$` will match a line containing a single `=`. Therefore you may prefer less compact, more restrictive expression, like this:

```
grep -E '^Model |^Metrics results:$|^metric |^====================$'
```

I assumed there are no trailing spaces in lines containing `Metrics results:` or `====================`. Because of these  `# This should be captured` you added I cannot really tell if it's a good assumption. Adjust the expression if needed (dropping one or both `$` anchors may be an adjustment).

Tested with GNU `grep` 3.7.

---

An overview of syntax used:

- `grep -E` makes `grep` interpret patterns as Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). `grep` without `-E` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE). Your problem can be solved with BRE. I chose ERE because the patterns look simpler (i.e. they are more human-readable).
- `foo|bar|baz` matches `foo` or `bar` or `baz`. This requires `grep -E`. Without `-E` it would be `foo\|bar\|baz`.
- `^` at the beginning of an expression is an anchor matching the beginning of the line.
- Similarly `$` at the end matches the end of the line.
- `[Mm]` matches either `M` or `m`.
- `s?` matches zero or one `s`. This requires `-E`. Without `-E` it would be `s\?`<sup>1</sup>.
- `=+` matches one or more `=` characters. This requires `grep -E`. Without `-E` it would be `=\+`<sup>1</sup>. Or one can use `==*` for this (where `=*` matches zero or more `=` characters).

The first command without `-E`:

```
grep '^Model \|^[Mm]etrics\? \|^==*$'
```

<sup>1</sup> [`\?` and `\+` are not part of the POSIX BRE standard though](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

---

You probably know this, but just in case: you filter the stdout of some `cmmnd` with

```
cmmnd | grep …
```